# How to denote the number of parameters needed to define such a model where variables have different number of states with big O notation?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

["Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective by Kevin Patrick Murphy"](http://noiselab.ucsd.edu/ECE228/Murphy_Machine_Learning.pdf) in page 44 says

> A joint probability distribution has the form p(x1,...,xD) for a set of D > 1 variables, and models the (stochastic) relationships between the variables. If all the variables are discrete, we can represent the joint distribution as a big multi-dimensional array, with one variable per dimension. However, the number of parameters needed to define such a model is $O(K^D)$, where K is the number of states for each variable.

In this example

> Suppose that 3 balls are randomly selected from an urn containing 3
>   red, 4 white, and 5 blue balls. If we let X and Y denote,
>   respectively, the number of red and white balls chosen, then the joint
>   probability mass function of X and Y, p(i,j) = P{X=i,Y=j}

[image]

p(0,0)=P(X=0,Y=0) means 0 red, 0 white and 3 blue balls.

p(3,0)=P(X=3,Y=0) means 3 red, 0 white and 0 blue balls.

All of variable ($x_1$, ..., $x_n$) have the same number of possible values (number of states), $K_1=...=K_D=4$

How to denote the number of parameters needed to define such a model where variables have different number of states? $K_1$ does not necessarily equal to $K_D$

Answer (score 1):

Denote$$\Bbb P(X_1=x_1,\ldots,X_D=x_D)=p(x_1,\ldots,x_D)$$Then if $x_1$ can take $K$ possible values, $\ldots$, $x_D$ can take $K$ possible values, the vector $(x_1,\ldots,x_D)$ can take
$$K \times \cdots \times K = K^D$$
values. Therefore the joint distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_D$ is defined by the $K^D$ values of the function $p(x_1,\ldots,x_D)$. Note that, as in the example, some of these values may be null or constrained, for instance by
$$\sum_{(x_1,\ldots,x_D)\\\in\{1,\ldots,K\}^D} p(x_1,\ldots,x_D) = 1$$Hence the actual number of parameters is of order $K^D$, denoted as $O(K^D)$. This $O(K^D)$ collection of parameters determines the joint distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the context of balls example, what do $\Bbb P, p, X_1, x_1$ represent?

Comment: I suggest that (a) you add `self-study` as a tag and (b) you first attempt on your own the correspondence between the general framework and the urn example. This would tell us where the difficulty in your understanding of the model stands.

Comment: thank for your reminder. in this example

p(0,0)=P(X=0,Y=0) means 0 red, 0 white and 3 blue balls.

p(3,0)=P(X=3,Y=0) means 3 red, 0 white and 0 blue balls.

is D equal to 2 or 3 in this case?